# Jquery: how do i apply Empty Text to all textboxes, not just 1

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

I have this script which will put the tool tip text from a textbox as it's "Empty Text".  Then when you click on it, the empty text disappears and reappears if you Blur and the textbox is still empty.

```
var $textbox = $("#MainContent_tbCity"); // select single box (how get all?)
        $textbox.focus(function () {
            if ($textbox.val() == this.title) {
                $textbox.val("");
                $textbox.removeClass("LightText");
            }                    
        });
        $textbox.blur(function () {
            if ($textbox.val() == "") {
                $textbox.val(this.title);
                $textbox.addClass("LightText");
            }                
        });
        $textbox.blur();
```

Comment: What's the problem??, provide short and working example

Comment: Why not use the `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: Get a selector that matches all textboxes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the `placeholder` attribute. It was created for that purpose. However, if you want to manually manage your placeholder text here is how:

```
$(function() {
        $(':text').on('focus', function () {
            if (this.value == this.title) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass("LightText");
            }                    
        })
        .on('blur', function () {
            if ( this.value.trim() == "" ) {
                $(this).val(this.title).addClass("LightText");
            }                
        })
        .blur();
});
```

Comment: As a follow-up question, why is this not working on the first page load, only after a refresh?  The textboxes in question are in an updatepanel but on the first page load, the function doesn't seem to be running

Comment: Please provide a demo here or on jsfiddle.